# sum 2 columns in a reporting services matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008

I have matrix in my report having column field "Layer Origin".

Layer Origin has 3 values:

1. New Business
2. Renewal - Rewritten
3. Renewal - Same Terms

if i run the report as is it will show Totals for each of the 3 above.

What i what is to show the Totals for:

1. New Business
2. Renewal (Renewal - Rewritten + Renewal - Same Terms)

i.e.: i want to sum the values of Renewal-Rewritten and Renewal- Same Terms
Below is a screen shot to illustrate my request.

[image]

---

Thanks for your reply.
ive tried the below code but it gave me error (see the below screen)

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Layer_Origin.Value="New Business",0,Fields!USD_Cedent_Premium.Value))
```

[image]

I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Several testing i found the problem.
the code should be as below:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Layer_Origin.Value="New Business",CDec(0.00),Fields!USD_Cedent_Premium.Value))
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

This situation can be handle if you just use conditional SUM in Total Column

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Layer_Origin.Value="New Business",0,Fields!USD_CED.Value))
```

Instead of using

```
=SUM(Fields!USD_CED.Value)
```

I think it will solve your problem. Pardon me if some spell mistake or syntax error. As i dont have any VS intalled to check.
Share if you still face any issue bcz this one is definetly i can help.